# Most correct "noun suffix" for "living in X" or "resident of X"?

Tags: suffixes, nouns

Not sure if that is the best title, but I wasn't sure the best way to word it.  We all know you can say "(originally) (comes) from X" as simply `X出身`.

> - 私はニューヨーク出身です　→　I'm from New York
> - 鹿児島出身の平田さん　→　Mr. Hirata from Kagoshima

So I'm looking for something analogous to this to say "living in X" or "resident of X".  I was thinking possibly `X居住`, `X[在居]{ざい・きょ}`, or `X[在住]{ざい・じゅう}`.

> - 私は大阪在住です　→　I'm living in Osaka
> - [上海]{シャン・ハイ}居住の日本人　→　Japanese living in Shanghai

Are any of those correct/acceptable/used to convey this meaning?  Possibly some other noun I haven't listed?  Note that I'm looking for a "noun suffix" of the form `<place> + <suffix>`, not complete clauses/sentences like

> - どこから来ましたか？　私は**オーストラリアです**。
> - **イタリアに住んでいる**私の姉

Comment: X在住 is most common.

Comment: Why would you call that a suffix?

Comment: I think the OP was aware that 'suffix' was perhaps not ideal (hence their first sentence), so they tried their best to explain precisely what they meant by it.  I don't think people should downvote just because 'suffix' isn't the right technical term, since it's clear what they're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X在住` is the closest answer for your question.
This can be used like `私は東京在住です。` and `東京在住の日本人`.

Also `X居住` is acceptable.
The difference between them is where the subject is living, which here means X.

X in `X在住` are like country, province, city or village.

X in `X居住` are like house, apartment.

Answer (score -1):

More "correct" can be a bit misleading.  Do you mean more common?

Generally you need to keep the answer grammatically compatible to the question.  Also keep in mind the other ways the same questions will be asked:

```
どこの国の人ですか？  
出身はどちらですか？
お住まいはどこですか？
故郷はどこですか？
```

For the most part you'd just answer these in noun form: アメリカです、東京です、or whatever. That being said, I've found you can be a bit more liberal in mixing it up than you can in English, so keep that in mind.

Also, definitely do not overlook the more common approach:

```
どこに住んでいますか？　東京に住んでいます。
オーストラリア人です。 - I'm from Australia
```

You will use all of these far more than 在住。

Comment: Why is more "correct" misleading?  It is common to hear people use "irregardless" in English, but that does not make it a real word.

Comment: Also, I feel like you didn't really read my question very well.  I did not even use the word "common" at all.  I acknowledged `Ｘに住んでいる` and `Ｘです`, but was looking specifically for something *NOT* those.  Also, why are you assuming there will be a question?  I didn't mention using this to answer a question at all.

Comment: Something is either correct or it's not.  Assuming we could enumerate answers, how would the be assigned?  Poor choice of words either way.

I read your question.  Which is why *asked* if you meant more common.  Would I have asked you if you meant common if you actually used that word?  And finally, there's a question in your 3rd code block.

Comment: @istrasci More "correct" is misleading precisely because some people think "irregardless" is not a real word. Use dictates realness, not style guides.

Comment: @alexhatesmil:  Why are you even on this site then?  Just use Japanese however you want, and it will be correct.

Comment: @istrasci If a word's meaning and syntactic function are discernible, and it has entered the lexicon of at least a portion of the native speaker population, then it is absolutely a word. Just because you find "irregardless" disagreeable doesn't mean that it is not, in fact, real.    "Correctness" might be a useful concept for a person just beginning to learn a language, but we all know we use plenty of "incorrect" English and Japanese every single day.